# Upload/Store big CSV files in Oracle DB and update the files on subsequent uploads

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

Could somebody please let me know the best way to store a csv file in oracle DB(note :  number of columns in csv file are unknown to me, and I don't want to create an equivalent table for every csv file that gets uploaded)

My requirement is like below :

1. On first upload, just save the entire csv file in some column of a table.
2. On second upload, I want to merge the new content with the older one.

Example : first upload has data for the duration jan-2020 to dec-2020(some 2000 rows) and second upload has data for duration jan-2021 to dec-2021(some 1000 rows). Now by merge I basically mean, I want to combine data for (jan-2020 to dec-2020) and (jan-2021 to dec-2021) and store the result(3000 rows) back in CSV_DATA column shown below.

First upload

```
ID    MODIFIED_DATE      CSV_DATA
1     2/2/2021           ...
2     3/2/2021           ...
```

second upload for ID = 1

```
ID    MODIFIED_DATE      CSV_DATA
1     20/2/2021          ...
2     3/2/2021           ...
```

Many thanks in advance !!!

Comment: And what are you doing with these CSV 'dumps' in the database after they're 'loaded?'

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"?  Do you just want to append the new data?  Or are you trying to update data from a prior file?  If so, how do you know what the key to do the merge is?

Comment: @JustinCave I just want to append data, the previous data in the old file will not be modified, only new rows from new upload will be added.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith this data will be used for some calculations

Comment: How are you going to be doing calculations on CSV files whose structure you don't know?  Technically, you certainly could create a `clob` column and just append the new data to the `clob` column every time you load a new file.  But that would be a very unusual design and doing any sort of calculations on the data would be much slower than if you loaded the data into a relational table initially.  Since reads generally happen much more often than loads, that is generally a poor trade-off.

Comment: @JustinCave thanks for the response! My problem is there will be 100s of IDs and for each ID I have one CSV file(having at least 15 columns). I want to go for a column storage approach to avoid maintaining 100s of tables.

Comment: But if each CSV has a different structure, you'd likely end up with hundreds of different pieces of code to parse the different files in order to perform whatever calculations you plan on performing.  I'd much rather have hundreds of different tables than hundreds of pieces of code that each parse a single row of data from this one table.

Comment: Our advice, don't do what you're doing. Use external tables instead. Or I should say, my advice.

Answer (score 1):

Add a column with timestamp and keep only the new data after updating your table

Comment: that's not what am looking for, I have updated my question.. please read it once more.. thanks for answering